# Expansion of log(1-p)/(-p)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am struggling to prove the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(1-p)}{-p}
=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} p^{k-1}
=
1 + \frac{1}{2}p + \frac{1}{3}p^2 + \frac{1}{4}p^3 + \dots
\end{align}
where $p \in (0, 1)$.

---

This equality holds. See this `R` code:

```
p=.9
k=1:100
A=sum((1/k) * (p^(k-1)))
B=log(1-p) / (-p)
A; B  # Display
```

---

I tried Taylor expansion. Let
\begin{align}
f(p)=\frac{\log(1-p)}{-p},
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
f^{(1)}(p)=\frac{1}{(1-p)p} + p^{-2} \log(1-p).
\end{align}
But I don't know at which point I expand this function $f(p)$.

---

Any hints are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $p\in (-1,1)$.
$$\log'(1-p)=-\frac{1}{1-p}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k.$$

Integrate and conclude.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer, as the Maclaurin series of 1/(1-p) does not have term (-1)^k.

Answer (score 0):

Surb's answer above works! Here I put my own solution inspired by Surb's. The idea is that I don't need to worry about the denominator at all.
Let
$$
f(p) = \log(1-p),
$$
we have Taylor expansion
$$
f(p) = - \left[
p + \frac{1}{2} p^2 + \frac{1}{3} p^3 + \frac{1}{4} p^4 + \dots
\right].
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{f(p)}{-p} = 
1 + \frac{1}{2} p + \frac{1}{3} p^2 + \frac{1}{4} p^3 + \dots
$$